# I want the below JavaScript program to give the outputs in the browser (instead of console), how can I do that?

Tags: javascript

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm0Wz.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgfAC.png)

```
<p id ="Prime"></p>

    <script>
    const lowernumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the lower number : "));
    const highernumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the higher number : "));
    let i;
    let j; 
    let y ="";

     
    for (i=lowernumber;i<=highernumber;i++)
    {
       let flag =0;
        for (j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
            
        if(i>1)
        {
            if(flag==0)
            {
            console.log("Prime numbers are :" + i); 
            }
        
           else
            {
            y+=i + "</br>";
            document.getElementById("prime").innerHTML= "Composite numbers are : " + '</br>' +y;
            }
        
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I wrote this JavaScript program to find out both Prime and composite Numbers in an interval, also i got the output, but I got the output in two different places like in the console and the browser.
But I want both the outputs to be displayed in the browser only instead of in the console, How i can do that?

Comment: See function `document.write()`, as one possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating to p tags.

```
<p id ="Prime"></p>
<p id ="Composite"></p>
```

And like you did show composite numbers on p tag, you can copy this work for prime numbers.

```
<p id ="Prime"></p>
<p id ="Composite"></p>

<script>
const lowernumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the lower number : "));
const highernumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the higher number : "));
let i;
let j; 
let y = "";
let z = "";

 
for (i=lowernumber;i<=highernumber;i++)
{
   let flag =0;
    for (j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
        
    if(i>1)
    {
        if(flag==0)
        {
            y + = i + "</br>";
            document.getElementById("Prime").innerHTML= "Prime numbers are : " + '</br>' + y;
        }

        else
        {
            z + = i + "</br>";
            document.getElementById("Composite").innerHTML= "Composite numbers are : " + '</br>' + z;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: My code is working now after I have used <span> tags (each with its own ID) inside the <p> element.

<p><span id ="Prime"></span><span id ="Composite"></span></p>

Answer (score 0):

Stop use console.log(). Crate a new html element. Then use document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = your prime number